# SVG image overflows from the container

Tags: flutter, dart

I just learn flutter, but i have trouble when deal with images, here is a SVG images, it not fit into `container`, no matter how i use `fit: Boxfit` , please help, thank a lots.

here is the code of `Container`

```
Column(
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: (){
                          print("heeloo");
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            border: Border.all(width: 1.5)
                          ),
                          height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.12,
                          width: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.12,
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            newChat,
                            //fit: B,
                            height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.1,
                            width: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.1,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(
                        "New Chat",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: fontBold,
                          fontSize: 25,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
```

Here is result

[image: pic]

but i want something like this

[image: pic]

Comment: Hey, can you add your newchat svg

Comment: ff course , i will add it right now

Comment: herre is my svg https://svgur.com/s/WQb

Comment: here is full code https://wtools.io/paste-code/b4FV

Comment: i have answered  , you can upvote if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add some padding in the container `padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)`

```dart
 Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: Border.all(width: 1.5)
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/WQb.svg",
                  //fit: B,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: first, thank you for answer my question, but unluckily, this method not work, here is result https://ibb.co/QYNzpRr

Comment: It work !!!! Thank you a lot, i see you add `padding:EdgeInsets.all(10)`

Answer (score 1):

Adding the padding `padding:  EdgeInsets.all(5),` to the container works like charm.

Comment: i upvoted, i really really help for beginner like me, thank you a lot

Comment: You can make that padding respoonsive as well like this `padding: EdgeInsets.all( SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.01)`

Comment: thank you, i'll do it, but now i'm stuck with animation, can we make ripples effect on Container like this?